# Broadcom BCM43228 bluetooth adapter not detected

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, 22.04

I recently switched out my old mPCIe with a Broadcom BCM43228 mPCIe.

```sh
$ lspci | grep -i broadcom
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i broadcom
[    6.013433] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4359 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
```

After installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` via `sudo apt bcmwl-kernel-source` and rebooting, wifi seems to be working perfectly, however Ubuntu doesn't seem to be detecting the bluetooth adapter at all. How do I resolve this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'd really like to use my bluetooth headset again soon.

---

##### Additional information

```sh
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

```sh
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```sh
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```sh
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jun 21 16:58:51 sujit-Vostro-3446 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jun 21 16:59:31 sujit-Vostro-3446 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

After running these commands, the bluetooth service seems to be running, but bluetoothctl gives no controller detected.

```sh
$ sudo modprobe btusb
$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-06-21 17:13:10 IST; 3s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 2959 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9339)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 99ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─2959 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 21 17:13:09 sujit-Vostro-3446 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 21 17:13:10 sujit-Vostro-3446 bluetoothd[2959]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Jun 21 17:13:10 sujit-Vostro-3446 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 21 17:13:10 sujit-Vostro-3446 bluetoothd[2959]: Starting SDP server
Jun 21 17:13:10 sujit-Vostro-3446 bluetoothd[2959]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
```

```sh
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   65.201308] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   65.201365] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   65.201369] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   65.201376] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   65.201380] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   65.201389] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   72.274957] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   72.274962] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   72.274967] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```sh
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: @chili555 I'm afraid that command gives no output at all. I tried it both before and after `sudo modprobe btusb && sudo systemctl start bluetooth`. I tried it with the `-i` flag as well.

Comment: @chili555, I've seen some people have written that for Broadcom, a bluetooth firmware needs to be installed but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do for this particular hybrid model.

Comment: So far, we see no bluetooth device at all. Is there any option regarding bluetooth in the BIOS/EFI?

Comment: @chili555 yes, bluetooth is enabled in BIOS. Also I'm able to use bluetooth properly with my old atheros network card.

Comment: @chili555 I found someone else with the same issue, but they had no luck either https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=368916 :(

Comment: @chili555 I tried switching to the b43 driver, but it gave the exact same result. WiFi works but bluetooth doesn't. I don't know why linux is not even recognising the bluetooth hardware. The WiFi is however terribly slow with this driver.

Comment: @chili555 I've edited my post with the output for `sudo dmesg | grep -i usb`. I noticed towards the end there are a bunch of USB errors, I don't think they were there before so it might be related. Do you know what *device descriptor read/64, error -32* means? Does this mean this is a hardware issue and nothing can be done?

Comment: I don't think USB interface is used here

Comment: @Pilot6 I've read online that for the bluetooth part of the mPCIe, it should show up under `usb-devices`, i'm not sure though. But yeah that error suddenly disappeared after restarting.

Comment: Please post output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` If the device is not shown by `lsusb`, it won't work. But there are some Broadcom BT devices that work differently. But the log should show the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's empty, and when I restart the bluetooth service as mentioned in the question I see that output. But basically it's empty.

Comment: @Pilot6 `dmesg | grep -i broadcom` shows a broadcom wireless hybrid controller, but the bluetooth part of it is no where to be found.

Comment: "I've edited my post with the output for sudo dmesg | grep -i usb" I don't see it. "Do you know what device descriptor read/64, error -32 means?" I'd like to see the three lines preceeding it and the entire line exactly. I suspect it is a hardware issue.

Comment: @chili555 if you take a look at the edit history of the post you can see the full log. I deleted it because after removing the battery, all USB connections, then putting it back as a few posts said to do if this error shows up and the errors stopped coming. The bluetooth however was still not detected so I assumed it was not related.